# What is the word for how polyprotic an acid is?

Tags: acid-base, terminology

What is the word to describe the number of acidic hydrogens an acid has? I am currently thinking something like "proticity", but I am not sure  The use case world be for a table of things like this:

```
Acid    | Proticity
--------------------
CH₃COOH |  1
H₂SO₄   |  2
H₃BO₃   |  3
```

Or in a set of statements like this:

> The volume of gas produced by reaction A was 4.6 L. The proticity of Acid B was 3. The tare mass of object C was 4.76 g. The density of substance D was 7.8 g/mL.

Is there a specific word used to refer to this quantity? What word should I use to refer to it?

Comment: I don't know if there is an accepted term, but if there is not one, let's use "proticity". I like it.

Answer (score 11):

The term that I learned was (ironically) "[basicity](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081224234255AAJxP4y)."

I'm not sure if that's the standard term, or even if there is a standard term, but this refers to how many bases you need to neutralize the acid completely.

EDIT: Thanks for the correction from LDC3: the "basicity" of an acid refers to how many bases you've already added to it. Thus, $\ce{NaH2PO4}$ would be "sodium phosphate, monobasic," $\ce{Na2HPO4}$ would be "sodium phosphate, dibasic," and so on.

Again, not sure if this is standard terminology.

Comment: If you go to a chemical site (like Sigma-Aldrich) the formula $\ce {NaH2PO4}$ is called phosphoric acid, monobasic and $\ce {Na2HPO4}$ is called phosphoric acid, dibasic because of the number of bases (2 NaOH) use to get the compound.

Comment: This is accepted terminology AFAIK. I've seen Wikipedia use it too consistently across articles, and I've seen chemical bottles use "sodium phosphate, monobasic" (or "dibasic") as you mentioned.

Comment: @LDC3 You might be right. Unfortunately, Sigma Aldrich seems to be down for me right now. I will check and update the answer when it comes online, but curiously, Wikipedia seems to say the opposite. Maybe an editor got confused one day?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dibasic

Comment: Checked the sigma and other sources, and I stand corrected.

Answer (score 4):

*Proticity* does sound nice, but it is a bad choice since the term has already been introduced by *Peter D. Mitchell* (1978 Nobel Prize in Chemistry) in a completely different context.

In his [Nobel Lecture](http://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/chemistry/laureates/1978/mitchell-lecture.pdf), Peter D. Mitchell explains:

> I use the word proticity for the force and flow of
>   the proton current by analogy with the word electricity, which describes
>   the force and flow of an electron current.

Comment: Very interesting. What would you propose, then?

Comment: @ringo Honestly, I don't know a good noun in English (or German). In both languages, I have always used inelegant constructions (multiprotonic acids / mehrprotonige Säuren) instead.

Comment: I think the context is different enough that we can cope with the identical word meaning different things. There are other examples, where it’s much worse.

Answer (score 2):

Monoprotic, [Diprotic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diprotic_acid), Trioprotic, tetraprotic, pentaprotic, hexaprotic, septaprotic, octaprotic....

{edit}

I then suggest "[equivalents factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalent_concentration)," which is directly related to the concept of normality:

"Normality isn't the same like Molarity, but you can say N = M * equivalents. 1 M HCl = 1 N HCl, but 1 M H2SO4 = 2 N H2SO4..." -[source](http://www.sciencemadness.org/talk/viewthread.php?tid=3798)

Comment: I already know those words; what I am looking for is a word for the number itself.