# What do you call acids that can disassociate more than 1 H+

Tags: acid-base

What do you call acids that can disassociate more than 1 H+? Is it like Class n acids for acids that can disassociate n H+?

Comment: diprotic acid = 2, triprotic =3, polyprotic acid.

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16804/what-is-the-word-for-how-polyprotic-an-acid-is